# How to set ItemTemplate text value to combobox DataTextField instead of DataValueField

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik radgrid with a GridTemplateColumn as seen below in a C# ASP.NET 4.0 webform.

As you can see, in the EditItemTemplate I am using a RadComboBox with an id number for DataValueField and a human readable text for DataTextField.

My question is, how can I change the Text in my ItemTemplate to show the human readable value instead of the Id?  The value Alias1 comes from the grid datasource and it is the Id.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Alias1" Display="true" DataField="Alias1" HeaderText="Alias1" SortExpression="Alias1">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="lblField30" CssClass="text" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Alias1") %>'></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <EditItemTemplate> 

            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox16" runat="server" Skin="Outlook" Height="150" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceAliasOptions" DataTextField="aliasText" DataValueField="aliasid"  SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Alias1") %>'>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>

    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change ItemTemplate binding like this:

```
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="lblField30" CssClass="text" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("aliasText") %>'></asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>
```

Of course your binded entity must have "aliasText" property. If you are binding something like DataTable make sure that contains "aliasText" column.

Comment: Hi @Gregor Primar.  How to access lblField30 Text  value on UpdateCommand ?